# Search Engine in Website showing results from certain sites

Tags: wordpress, search-engine

I am currently planning to build a search engine website. I want my engine to search in certain other sites (let's say 10 sites) and return results from them. One way to achieve that is do it from scratch: build spiders that would scan sites, build a data base of products and index them and then a simple search mechanism to return results. Is there an easier way to do that (maybe using plugins in CMSs like Wordpress?), free or payed? Which way to build it would be more efficient and fast?

Comment: Note that i do not want to search my own website. I want my website to be a search engine that searches othes websites. I've found plugins like WPSolr and Elastic search but they do not seem helpful.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no Plugin for WordPress like this.